# How to delete pending changes in ui5?

Tags: sapui5

I get three pending changes from `oModel.getPendingChanges()`, oModel is [sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel)

```
{
    {
        ASet('id1') : {id: 1}
    },
    {
        BSet('id1') : {id: 1}
    },
    {
        CSet('id1') : {id: 1}
    }
}
```

I just want submit ASet. B and C changes is from ComboBox select. I have three ComboBoxes that are related to each other. I used binding to solve that.

```
<ComboBox
    id="theSecondSelect"
    selectionChange="onChange"
    enabled="false"
    showSecondaryValues="true"
    value="{
        path: 'propertySetId',
        type: '.Utils.mandatoryValueType'}">
</ComboBox>
```

`<items>` is dynamically binding in controller.

I've even tried

```
for(var sBindingPath in oChanges) {
    if(sBindingPath.indexOf("ASet") === -1) {
        delete oModel.mChangedEntities[sBindingPath];

    }
}
console.log(oModel.getPendingChanges());
```

I can see that pending changes has already been deleted, but the three requests still sent.

Any suggestion?

---

Update:

Remove pending changes by

```
_resetSelectChanges: function() {
    var oChanges = this._oModel.getPendingChanges();

    for (var sBindingPath in oChanges) {
        if (sBindingPath.indexOf("ControlIoTImplementationSet") === -1) {
            this._oModel.resetChanges(["/" + sBindingPath]);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

But it will appear again after I close the form dialog.

[image]

Comment: v2.oDataModel has `resetChanges` function. Have you tried that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the API description of the `resetChanges` method [here](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel).

The method takes an array of strings as its parameter. Each string is a path of an entity which should be reset.

Sample call:

```
oModel.resetChanges(["/BSet('id1')", "/CSet('id1')"]);
```

This resets the changes of the two given entities. Thus only the changes to your `ASet('id1')` entity should be submitted.